# How to fusion two (or more) arrays without losing values in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Following the example given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44623098/4451521) I am trying to join two (actually more) images but I can not seem to make it right.
Since images are difficult to comprehend (for me) I made a simple example

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

layer1 = np.zeros((5, 5, 4))
layer2 = np.zeros((5,5,4))

green_color = (0, 66, 0, 0)
otro_color = (40,0,0,0)

cv2.rectangle(layer1, (1, 1), (3, 3), green_color, 1)
print(layer1)

cv2.line(layer2, (1, 1), (3, 3), otro_color, 1)
print(layer2)


res = layer1[:]
cnd = layer2[:, :, 0] > 0  
res[cnd] = layer2[cnd]  #<-- this is not working correctly

print(res)
```

As a result first I have a matrix

```
[[[  0.   0.   0.   0.]
  [  0.   0.   0.   0.]
  [  0.   0.   0.   0.]
  [  0.   0.   0.   0.]
  [  0.   0.   0.   0.]]

 [[  0.   0.   0.   0.]
  [  0.  66.   0.   0.]
  [  0.  66.   0.   0.]
  [  0.  66.   0.   0.]
  [  0.   0.   0.   0.]]

 [[  0.   0.   0.   0.]
  [  0.  66.   0.   0.]
  [  0.   0.   0.   0.]
  [  0.  66.   0.   0.]
  [  0.   0.   0.   0.]]

 [[  0.   0.   0.   0.]
  [  0.  66.   0.   0.]
  [  0.  66.   0.   0.]
  [  0.  66.   0.   0.]
  [  0.   0.   0.   0.]]

 [[  0.   0.   0.   0.]
  [  0.   0.   0.   0.]
  [  0.   0.   0.   0.]
  [  0.   0.   0.   0.]
  [  0.   0.   0.   0.]]]
```

Then I have the matrix

```
[[[  0.   0.   0.   0.]
  [  0.   0.   0.   0.]
  [  0.   0.   0.   0.]
  [  0.   0.   0.   0.]
  [  0.   0.   0.   0.]]

 [[  0.   0.   0.   0.]
  [ 40.   0.   0.   0.]
  [  0.   0.   0.   0.]
  [  0.   0.   0.   0.]
  [  0.   0.   0.   0.]]

 [[  0.   0.   0.   0.]
  [  0.   0.   0.   0.]
  [ 40.   0.   0.   0.]
  [  0.   0.   0.   0.]
  [  0.   0.   0.   0.]]

 [[  0.   0.   0.   0.]
  [  0.   0.   0.   0.]
  [  0.   0.   0.   0.]
  [ 40.   0.   0.   0.]
  [  0.   0.   0.   0.]]

 [[  0.   0.   0.   0.]
  [  0.   0.   0.   0.]
  [  0.   0.   0.   0.]
  [  0.   0.   0.   0.]
  [  0.   0.   0.   0.]]]
```

as expected. However when trying to fuse it I have

```
[[[  0.   0.   0.   0.]
  [  0.   0.   0.   0.]
  [  0.   0.   0.   0.]
  [  0.   0.   0.   0.]
  [  0.   0.   0.   0.]]

 [[  0.   0.   0.   0.]
  [ 40.   0.   0.   0.]
  [  0.  66.   0.   0.]
  [  0.  66.   0.   0.]
  [  0.   0.   0.   0.]]

 [[  0.   0.   0.   0.]
  [  0.  66.   0.   0.]
  [ 40.   0.   0.   0.]
  [  0.  66.   0.   0.]
  [  0.   0.   0.   0.]]

 [[  0.   0.   0.   0.]
  [  0.  66.   0.   0.]
  [  0.  66.   0.   0.]
  [ 40.   0.   0.   0.]
  [  0.   0.   0.   0.]]

 [[  0.   0.   0.   0.]
  [  0.   0.   0.   0.]
  [  0.   0.   0.   0.]
  [  0.   0.   0.   0.]
  [  0.   0.   0.   0.]]]
```

Which is not what I want. You can notice that in the second element everytime I apply 40 in the first channel, the 60 of the second channel dissappears.

What I want to get is

```
[[[  0.   0.   0.   0.]
  [  0.   0.   0.   0.]
  [  0.   0.   0.   0.]
  [  0.   0.   0.   0.]
  [  0.   0.   0.   0.]]

 [[  0.   0.   0.   0.]
  [ 40.  66.   0.   0.]
  [  0.  66.   0.   0.]
  [  0.  66.   0.   0.]
  [  0.   0.   0.   0.]]

 [[  0.   0.   0.   0.]
  [  0.  66.   0.   0.]
  [ 40.   0.   0.   0.]
  [  0.  66.   0.   0.]
  [  0.   0.   0.   0.]]

 [[  0.   0.   0.   0.]
  [  0.  66.   0.   0.]
  [  0.  66.   0.   0.]
  [ 40.  66.   0.   0.]
  [  0.   0.   0.   0.]]

 [[  0.   0.   0.   0.]
  [  0.   0.   0.   0.]
  [  0.   0.   0.   0.]
  [  0.   0.   0.   0.]
  [  0.   0.   0.   0.]]]
```

I've tried (without success) to do

```
res= layer1 | layer2  # does not work
```

also

```
cnd = np.logical_or(layer1,layer2)
```

which gives a nice mask of trues where I want to put values but then

```
res[cnd] = layer2[cnd]
```

ruins everything.

How can I fusion those arrays to get the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just add the two, right?

```
>>> res[cnd] += layer2[cnd]

>>> res
[[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]]

 [[ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
  [40. 66.  0.  0.]
  [ 0. 66.  0.  0.]
  [ 0. 66.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]]

 [[ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0. 66.  0.  0.]
  [40.  0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0. 66.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]]

 [[ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0. 66.  0.  0.]
  [ 0. 66.  0.  0.]
  [40. 66.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]]

 [[ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]]]
```